# Javascript P5 change a variable after mouseclick event

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I have a variable called `Asset1`

I want everytime I click on the button that `Asset1` goes to `Asset2`, `Asset3`, `Asset4` etc. It increases by 1.

But I don't know how to set up a variable which can change after you click on a button. I thought of something like this.

```
var Asset[x]; [x]++; // after the mouseclick event
```

I'm stuck, can someone assist?

Comment: You want to increment the variable's name? Or value?

Comment: The variable's name

Comment: The first time it is Asset1. And thereafter it must increase with 1. The variable's name. Asset2,Asset3,Asset4,Asset5 etcetera

Comment: Can you explain what exactly you want to achieve by incrementing variable names? Maybe there are better solutions to it

Comment: Yes! I have a assets window, which stores every asset I bought in the game. When I buy a house for example, I have this code which fills in Asset1. ``` Asset1= house_location + "     " + "Cost" + "     " + cost + "     " + "Downpay"+ "     " + downpay; ``` These are variables.

Comment: This works, but I don't want to do it everytime i buy a house. I want that it automatically knows you have bought a house once before, so 1 becomes 2. And then 3,4,5 etcetera. dependent on how much houses you have.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an array like below:

```
var assets = []

// Add to this array
assets.push(house_location + " " + "Cost" + " " + cost + " " + "Downpay"+ " " + downpay)

// Access a particular element eg. first
assets[0]

// Check if already have a house
assets.length > 0
```

Comment: I don't get it. Is it possible to invite you to have a look at my code? I can explain it better if I can share my code somewhere.

Comment: Create a code snippet in the question itself if you can, or use jsfiddle

Comment: Ah! I was trying this what you wrote, now it works. Thanks!

Comment: @Fari That's good. Please mark the answer as accepted by clicking the grey tick next to it :)

Comment: I am new in this field of programming. So most of the things doesn't go as fast as I want. I'm currently programming with ProcessingJS in editor p5. I was struggling with this for a while. Many thanks. Fari Jahangir

Comment: No problem, help will always be given at SO to those who put in the effort and ask when stuck

Comment: This is the program I'm working on. https://editor.p5js.org/FJ/full/U8VdIJi6m                             It is not finished. I'm experimenting why it does take a random value for house_location only once in the game, and not everytime I come across it.

Comment: Its good, all the best and you can ask again if you're stuck anywhere

Comment: I'm glad to hear that. Thank you. Have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

Increases value each time the button is clicked by calling a function.

```
//initialize number
    var i = 0;
    function clicked(n) { 
        //increase value by number of times clicked
        i = i + n;
        //get number element
        var number = document.getElementById("number");
        //Set number element to Document
        number.innerHTML = i;
    };
```

Codepen: https://codepen.io/AMSteffensen/pen/oNjjmaQ